# Reports and percents with calculated fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In Microsoft Access 2010 I am in Design View creating a new Report. I have two calculated fields and I would like to calculate a percentage figure with the two (percentage complete to be exact).

```
Fields:
     Field 1: =Count([Field1])
     Field 2: =Sum(IIf([Field 2],1,0))
```

I am trying to divide the calculated values of Field 2 by the calculated values of Field 1. But I am not sure about the appropriate approach. Any help would be appreciated. I would like to create a new text to be displayed on the report with the total.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out that you can use the text box values to calculate other calculations in expression builder.